# Swift how to increase margins of arranged views

Tags: swift

How can Increase the the margin of  different `UITextFields` inside a `UIStackView`. I need to increase the the top margin the margins will be the same.

```
  let formWrapperStackView:UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
            v.axis = .vertical
           // v.distribution = .fillProportionally
            v.spacing = 0
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return v
    }()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to have different `spacing` for different elements in a UIStackView. So a solution would be to wrap each of your `textfield`s with a `UIView` and then set the top constraint of each textfield (between textfield and UIView) to your desired margin.

Comment: great  idea on that, I dont see why apple would not add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you're looking for the `spacing` property of the stack view, which you're setting to 0. Change it to e.g. 15 to give some space between the stacked views.

Comment: the spacing will give the same amount for all arranged views I want to be able to change all of the to different spacing (example email.topmargin = 20, password.topmarging = 10) and so on